# Java 8 Predicate - why can't wildcard generics predicates be joined?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Consider the following code:

```
public class Main {
    private static Predicate<? extends TestObject> predicate = testObject -> true;
    private static Predicate<? extends TestObject> predicate1 = testObject -> true;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

         List<TestObject> objects = Lists.newArrayList( new TestObject(), new TestObject() );

         objects.stream().filter( predicate.or( predicate1 ) ).findFirst();
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile, giving the error:

```
Error:(17, 48) java: incompatible types: java.util.function.Predicate<capture#1 of ? extends test.test.TestObject> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Predicate<? super capture#2 of ? extends test.test.TestObject>
```

It seems like we can't join such predicates with logical operators like "or" or "and", but why can't Java deal with them?

It compiles with simple predicates like `Predicate<TestObject>`, but not with `Predicate<? super TestObject>` or `Predicate<? extends TestObject>`.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a wildcard here at all? If you just define it as `Predicate<TestObject>` it would accept anything that extends `TestObject`.

Comment: It is just an example to show the source of my curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might know that the predicates are compatible, but the compiler does not.

Imagine this example:

```
Predicate<? extends Collection<Object>> p1 = (Set<Object> s) -> s.isEmpty();
Predicate<? extends Collection<Object>> p2 = (List<Object> l) -> l.get(0) != null;
```

We developers can see that the first predicate could technically handle all collections, while the second one can handle only lists. But imagine the predicates were initialized somewhere else or would be changed in the meantime. The compiler cannot know for sure which type of collections the predicate objects were made for. As a result, you cannot use them at all:

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
p1.test(set);
p2.test(list);
p1.test(list);
p2.test(set);
```

All these calls won't compile, because the compiler cannot say whether the actual objects behind `p1` and `p2` can are exactly for those types of collections. That is the meaning of `? extends Collection<>`: You know it is a specific sub type, but you cannot tell the compiler which one exactly.

---

To illustrate this with a simpler example:

```
Collection<Apple> appleBasket = ...;
appleBasket.add(new Apple());  // works
appleBasket.add(new Orange()); // does not work (obviously)

Collection<Fruit> mixedFruitBasket = ...;
mixedFruitBasket.add(new Apple());  // works
mixedFruitBasket.add(new Orange()); // works

// Now the tricky part
Collection<? extends Fruit> unknownButPureFruitBasket = ...;
unknownButPureFruitBasket.add(new Apple());  // does not work 
unknownButPureFruitBasket.add(new Orange()); // does not work
```

You cannot add any one fruit to a basket whose type you don't know. It could in fact be a basket that accepts all fruit, but it could be a pure Apple basket, or Orange backet, or even a Banana basket that you do not even know of yet.

Try it in your IDE:

```
List<? extends String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.addAll(l2);
```

Eclipse tells me:

> The method addAll(Collection1-of ? extends String>) in the type List<capture#**1**-of ? extends String> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#**2**-of ? extends String>)

Note the different types: `addAll` expects a collection of `capture#1`, `l2` is a collection of `capture#2`.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that while a declaration like `Predicate<? extends Collection<Object>> p1 = Collection::isEmpty;` obviously initializes `p1` with a predicate that can handle all kinds of collections, nothing stops us from performing an assignment like `p1 = p2;` at a later point of time, as the types of these variables are compatible, both refer to predicates of an unknown subtype of collection. After all, that’s the main reason to declare variables with a broader type than the value we’re assigning to them, gain flexibility in the actual type of the value we’re assigning later-on.

Answer (score 4):

`filter` requires a `Predicate<? super TestObject>`, not `Predicate<? extends TestObject>`.

Why `super TestObject`? Because the TestObject here is an input parameter, a *consumer*. According to the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) rule, it should be marked super.

`Predicate<? extends TestObject>` is completely different from `Predicate<? super TestObject>`. The former can accept all subclasses of `TestObject` and `TestObject`. The latter can accept all superclasses of `TestObject` and `TestObject`. Obviously they are different and non-compatible.

Answer (score 3):

This is really not about how Java handles predicates, but it's simply a question of generics.

In short, the answer is that `predicate` and `predicate1` aren't necessarily compatible. The type of the parameter to `or` is `Predicate<? super T>`, assuming that `T` in the two `Predicate` objects is the same concrete type argument. But this is not the case.

To illustrate the problem, assume:

```
class TestObject2 extends TestObject {
    boolean isTrue() {
        return true;
    }
}
class TestObject3 extends TestObject {
    boolean isTrue3() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And (note that the declared types didn't change, but the actual lambda expressions did):

```
private static Predicate<? extends TestObject> predicate = 
        (TestObject2 testObject) -> testObject.isTrue();
private static Predicate<? extends TestObject> predicate1 = 
        (TestObject3 testObject) -> testObject.isTrue3();
```

In this example, `or` would be getting the wrong value (`predicate` accepts a `TestObject2` object, but in this case, it could be called with a `TestObject3` object).

How do you think `predicate1` would work in this `filter`?

```
Stream.of(new TestObject2(), new TestObject2()).filter(predicate.or(predicate1));
```

The fact is that the compiler is guaranteeing that `Predicate<? extends TestObject>` is compatible with both `Predicate<TestObject2>` and `Predicate<TestObject3>` (and that's as per the law of generics)

Answer (score 1):

This is PECS yet again, since you *consume* some `TestObject` via the `Predicate`, you would need `? super TestObject`